# Is there a word to fill the blank in "What the...?!" to make it polite & educate?

Tags: phrase-request

In [a review about Ninja Gaiden](https://youtu.be/6t2YvyLqw3c?t=2m51s), the author pointed out that the Ninja always says: "What the...?" to express his emotion.

So I think that there is noway to complete this sentence without making it rude & uneducated?

Rude:

- What the hell/heck?!
- What the f-word?

Uneducated:

- What the what?! (That's what the cartoon character Gumball said - What's that even mean, it's meaningless so I count it as uneducated)

So if you were the Ninja Gaiden and you were forced to complete what you had said (you had said "What the...?!" to express your anger/surprise/scare/... ), How would you complete to make sure you were a polite & educated person.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make it sound less harsh, then why don't you use a euphemism to do that? A euphemism, in case you didn't know, is a mild or indirect word or expression substituted for another word that's considered to be too harsh or blunt when referring to something unpleasant or embarrassing ([source](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/euphemism)). According to the majority of online dictionaries, **what the heck** and [**what the hey**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/what_the_hey) are "officially" defined as expressions used as euphemisms for **what the hell**. So, you could use those.

On the other hand, you could use **what in the world** which, I'm sure many would agree, could probably be considered what you call the polite version of *what the hell/heck*. Or you could use all these expressions interchangeably depending on the situation:

> What in the world are you doing?
>
> What in the world are these for?
>
> What the heck is going on here?
>
> What the hey...

Answer (score 1):

To supplement @MichaelRybkin’s excellent answer, there are also many variants on “What in the world?” For example, possibly in increasing order of exhaspiration:

> What on earth?
>
> What in heaven’s name?
>
> What on God’s green earth?
>
> What in the name of all that is holy?

Comment: [+1], hey, I like "What on God’s green earth?", I think I gonna use that.